# Можно ли задеплоить бота на Heroku с файлом.txt?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, heroku

В моей код я реализовал рассылку через бота с помощью файла.txt. (При активации бота */start*, *id* пользователя записывается в *joined.txt*, и после при команде */post (text)*, берет от туда *id*, и отправляет *text*)
Так вот, при попытке деплоя бота на Heroku, мне в логах пишет, что данный файл отсутствует, и из-за не происходит краш бота.
Хотя *joined.txt* находится в той же директории, что и сам бот.
Вопрос, что нужно сделать, чтобы Heroku воспринимала данный *txt* файл

Answer (score 1):

Из [официальной документации](https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted) к Heroku:

> The Heroku filesystem is ephemeral - that means that any changes to
> the filesystem whilst the dyno is running only last until that dyno is
> shut down or restarted. Each dyno boots with a clean copy of the
> filesystem from the most recent deploy. This is similar to how many
> container based systems, such as Docker, operate.

Это значит, что хероку имеет лишь временное хранилище, которое очищается после перезапуска программы. Советую вам использовать не ***.txt** файлы, а полноценные базы данных.

Heroku поддерживает множество плагинов, которые позволяют деплоить бд в облаке, при том, на некоторых тарифах - абсолютно бесплатно.

Вот вам [ссылка на официальную документацию](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql) по деплою базы данных на Heroku.

+ [Бонус, туториал по PostgreSQL](https://coderlessons.com/articles/php/khosting-postgresql-s-heroku)